# Creating custom ODOO shipping carrier?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

Are there any guides, documentations, tutorials, examples, ... anything about writing custom shipping carriers for Odoo.

I checked their store and most of the bigger ones (DHL, UPS, etc.) are being sold so there is nothing really to use to check "how they did it".

I have a carrier that I need to integrate and they have an API that I can use.

What is the right approach?

Comment: You can check the Delivery UPS OCA apps and Delivery TNT OCA for Odoo 13.0 in GitHub [
link](https://github.com/OCA/delivery-carrier/tree/13.0). You can check how they did it.

Comment: @WaleedMohsen I will look into that, see what can be done, thank you